# Filtering out columns based on certain criteria

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filtering

I have another question about manipulating data using pandas. I am trying to filer a column based on a certain criteria but can't seem to get the correct code.

I need to filter my data based on 'Income' that is in the range $1000000 to $2000000 and 'Debt Ratio' is more than 20%

I have tried the following code but keep getting either an error in my syntax or just a boolean True or False output.

```py
loans_df = loansdf[loans_df('Income')== range(1000000:2000000) & loans_df('Debt Ratio') > .20]
```

So my expected results are to be a visual showing the df based on these filters and I keep getting either errors or a True or False output!

Comment: If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you make your [question easier to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you need to add "(" and ")" around each bool, so it would be ```loans_df = loansdf[(loans_df('Income')== range(1000000:2000000)) & (loans_df('Debt Ratio') > .20)]
```

Comment: Careful on range(x:y).  Don't think it is valid python, nor would range(x,y) work in the context methinks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you are constructing the boolean mask, and the precedence of the operators.  It is worth reviewing the python language and how boolean masks get made w/ Pandas.  Here is a functioning solution, with the mask on one line so you can play around with the operators, precedence and other logic if you wish.  Also check the way the columns in the dataframe get referenced.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

from pandas.compat import StringIO

csvdata = StringIO("""
Income,Debt Ratio
5000000,.4
1000000,.4
1500000,.3
1500000,.1
""")

loans_df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")
mask = (loans_df['Income'] > 1000000) & (loans_df['Income'] < 2000000) & (loans_df['Debt Ratio'] > .20)
print (loans_df[mask])
```

Produces

```
2  1500000         0.3
```